# TypeError: <django.forms.fields.EmailField object at 0xb24a066c> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, json, python-2.7, serialization

I am trying to render/fetch a `instance` form field from server with ajax and want to display that field some where, so

**views.py**

```
def edit_book_email(request, book_id):
    book = Book.objects.get(id=book_id)
    form = BookEmailForm(instance = book)
    result = {
    'email_field':form.fields['email'],
    }
    print result,">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
    report_json = json.dumps(result, cls = DjangoJSONEncoder) 
    return HttpResponse(report_json, mimetype='application/json')
```

So from the above code , i am trying to get the emailfield from the form and want to send it as the json reposnse, so that i can use it in template whereever i need like

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                              url: action,
                              data: form_data,
                              success: function(response)
                                {
                                   var form_field = '{{response.email_field}}' 
                                   $('.custom_design').html()   
   }
                      });        


      });

   });
  <script> 
</head>
<div>
   <span id="custom_design"><span>
</div>
</html>
```

But i am facing the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Envs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/user/app/apps/apps-web_nw/projsite/apps/website/views.py", line 665, in edit_book_email
    report_json = json.dumps(result, cls = DjangoJSONEncoder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 264, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/home/apps/Envs/apps/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 103, in default
    return super(DjangoJSONEncoder, self).default(o)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 178, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <django.forms.fields.EmailField object at 0xb24a066c> is not JSON serializable
```

Can anyone please let me know how to avoid this error and render an Email on html ?

Comment: And for sure i want to send the form object to html template, so that i can render the fields like form.email_field ....

Comment: Yeah, but you want to serialize the data and not the actual object, right? You're probably wanting to return the HTML of the field or the data within that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the html of the field, you need to render the `BoundField` like this:

```
result = {
    'email_field': str(form['email']),
}
```

Its a little unclear what you are trying to do in your javascript. If your html is a django template, this line is going to be a problem:

```
var form_field = '{{response.email_field}}'
```

That will only work if `response` is passed to the template context. Otherwise, you cannot use django tags in javascript. If you just want to get the html for the field that you returned in your ajax view, do this:

```
var form_field = response.email_field;
```